# How to prevent visual studio breaking on exceptions from third party libraries if they do not directly throw

Tags: c#, debugging, exception, visual-studio-2017

For example here is a stack trace generated when an exception has been thrown in **mscorlib**. The exception was triggered from **devDept.Eyeshot.Control.Wpf**. The exception is handled in **devDept.Eyeshot.Control.Wpf**.

- do not want to be annoyed by this exception
- do not want to turn on **Debug just my code**
- do not want to block all exceptions thrown by mscorlib

[image]

So I try to set the [exception conditions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/03/31/break-on-exceptions-thrown-only-from-specific-modules-in-visual-studio-15-preview/) as

[image]

which results in

[image]

but I still get exceptions that are thrown through **devDept.Eyeshot.Control.Wpf** but originally come from **mscorlib.dll**.

Is this an impossible wish? Do the exception conditions only work on exceptions thrown directly from the modules specified and not by ones further down the stack. I don't really want to block all exceptions from mscorlib. I only want to filter out exceptions from mscorlib that are triggered from code in **devdept** code. These exceptions are internally handled in **devdept** code.

And I do not wish to turn of **Just My Code**, just filter out exceptions from devdept code because it is so noisy.

Comment: One of my colleague had similar issue with Telerik + VS combo. He kick off a Visual Studio where he debugged another Visual Studio where he developed some stuff based on telerik library. This way he was able to catch or even getting some clue what went wrong.

Comment: I have not switched to VS 2017 specifically for this issue. This must be something new to 2017 because it doesn't happen in previous versions, I get all kinds of errors in Microsoft's libraries... and I'm like: "These are Microsoft's problems, why are they telling me about it?" I switched back to VS 2015 and I'll just wait until they resolve this issue.

Comment: If you turn `on`/`off` "Just My Code"  you `do get all` / `don't get any` exceptions from third party libraries. This is a feature not a bug

Comment: I also didn't find a way to do this. When exception is thrown in third party library - exception conditional will not look up the stack, only at the location where exception was actually thrown, as you discovered. And because you disabled Just My Code it seems you cannot break on unhandled exceptions only.

Comment: @evk That's really dissapointing. It seems like a job only half done. Looking up the stack should be pretty easy to do.

Comment: At least it clearly states that in description: "break when the following conditions are satisfied for the _location_ of thrown exception".

Comment: I was tempted to interpret `location` as the path path the exception travels up the stack. Seems I was too optimistic. :(